# Networking: what is the difference between access network and core network

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between access network, transport network and core network?

What is an access network aggregation network and what is a core network l?

Comment: Ask your professor.  This isn't a homework site.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Cisco's [spine-leaf architecture](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/white-paper-c11-737022.html) - essentially the core network provides connectivity across the whole diameter while the access network provides end-user uplinks. The aggregation network is in between, providing sufficient port numbers between access and core.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains in detail the differences in the hierarchy of topologies
http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9781587133329/downloads/ch01.pdf

Comment: Please don't post link only answers and consider adding some more details to your own answer so it remains useful even when the linked URL is not available anymore.